# express-jwt-blacklist throw an error like as Error: JWT missing tokenId claimsub in my code

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, express-jwt, jwt

I am developing MEAN stack application. for session authentication I used **express-jwt**.

My code is working very well with express-jwt token but when I log out then I want to remove jwt token / add token in black list.

So when I apply **express-jwt-blacklist** with jwt token it throws an error.Error: **JWT missing tokenId claimsub**

> My working code

```
=> In middleware / config file
const expressJWT = require("express-jwt");

CONFIG.JWTTOKENALLOWACCESS = expressJWT({
        secret: CONFIG.JWTTOKENKEY,
        userProperty: 'payload'
    });


=> In routing file
router.route("/get-post-list").get(CONFIG.JWTTOKENALLOWACCESS, PostCtrl.getPostList);
```

> My not working code (after apply express-jwt-blacklist)

```
=> In middleware / config file
const expressJWT = require("express-jwt");
const blacklist = require('express-jwt-blacklist');

CONFIG.JWTTOKENALLOWACCESS = expressJWT({
    secret: CONFIG.JWTTOKENKEY,
    userProperty: 'payload',
    isRevoked: blacklist.isRevoked
});


=> In routing file
router.route("/get-post-list").get(CONFIG.JWTTOKENALLOWACCESS, PostCtrl.getPostList);
```

> Error throws

```
error: "JWT missing tokenId claimsub"
```

Please help me to resolve this.

Comment: It looks like you might be missing a key value pair in your JSON.

Comment: if missing a key value pair in JSON, then it should not work before apply express-jwt-blacklist. but it works very well without applying express-jwt-blacklist

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue resolved by adding tokenId in blacklist.configure like as bellow

```
=> In middleware / config file
const expressJWT = require("express-jwt");
const blacklist = require('express-jwt-blacklist');

blacklist.configure({
    tokenId: 'jti',
    // strict: true,
    // store: {
    //     type: 'memcached',
    //     host: 'localhost',
    //     port: 3001,
    //     keyPrefix: 'mywebapp:',
    //     options: {
    //         timeout: 1000
    //     }
    // }
});

CONFIG.JWTTOKENALLOWACCESS = expressJWT({
    secret: CONFIG.JWTTOKENKEY,
    userProperty: 'payload',
    isRevoked: blacklist.isRevoked
});


=> In routing file
router.route("/get-post-list").get(CONFIG.JWTTOKENALLOWACCESS, PostCtrl.getPostList);
```

Make sure you must have set jti params/field at jwt login time like as bellow

```
const randToken = require('rand-token');
const jwt = require("jsonwebtoken");

...
...
...

user.myToken = jwt.sign({
    jti : user._id + "_" + randToken.generator({ chars: '0-9' }).generate(6);
    first_name : user.first_name,
    last_name : user.last_name,
    ...
    ...
    ...
}, jwt token key, {
    expiresIn: '7d' //7 days
});
```